# bitbucket branch shows tags like "MAIN" "DEVELOPMENT". these tags came automatically

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

[image]

[image]

bitbucket showing tags as I underline in the above image.

1. how can I add that kind of tag to the branch.
2. I'm trying to add [deployment variables](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/) to "development" and "production" environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those reflect the **[branching model](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/branch-a-repository/#The-branching-model)** chosen

You can change them in the settings of your repository:

[image: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/42115i11C96514EE25781C/image-size/large?v=v2&px=999]

> I was able to change this setting from the `General > Repository Details`  sidebar menu tab.
>
> In the main content area, there is an `Advanced` section that is closed by default.
> Open it and there are other settings, including one for "`Main branch`"